# missing manifest when using plugin in android studio

Tags: android-studio, plugins, manifest

I have developed an app on eclipse and I lately started working with android studio, when I first moved the app all the dependencies were moved smoothly without any problem,
now I am trying to add the feature to share through Facebook and twitter, but for twitter whenever I try to use any plugin in the build.gradle the manifest disappears. As shown in the code below:

**build.gradle (Project: project name)**
The problem is in this file:

```
 // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
 apply plugin: com.android.application

 buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
    //maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
    //classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'

     }
 }
 //apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

 allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
   // maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
     }
 }
 /*dependencies {
compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.14.1@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
 }

 android {
sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
     }
 }*/
```

**build.gradle (Module:app)**

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.0 rc4'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.nwf.ICDLeKitab"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 14
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),              'proguard-project.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/icu4j-4_4_2_2.jar')
    compile files('libs/jsoup-1.6.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
    compile files('libs/zip4j_1.2.6.jar')
    //compile project('com.facebook:facebook-android-sdk-4.0.1')
}
```

Can someone explain for me what is it happening? and how should I work with     Libraries and dependencies in android studio.

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "manifest disappears"?

Comment: usually you have in your project: app: manifest and under it java. the manifest part wouldn't show anymore, although it still exist in the main folder, but in the Android Studio it stop showing, plus I get Gradle sync failed

Comment: This happens whenever I try to add any plugin. Even when I add apply plugin: com.android.application as I have seen in several examples online, but it also causes the same error.

Comment: It might not be showing because Studio is not done with Gradle sync. What is the error?

Comment: Gradle sync failed: Could not find property 'com' on root project 'AppProject'.
           Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)

Comment: In your above gradle file, you have an unnecessary tilde (`\``). Does removing it help? Also, I don't see why you have added that `sourceSets` block. Comment it if removing tilde doesn't work

Comment: That's a typo while taking the screenshot, it's removed while testing.

Comment: even without the sourceSet same issue. As soon as I add the plugin I get the error. I added it for on one answer concerning the absence of the manifest, they suggested to add that part, but even when I comment it out, I clean project and build same error.

Comment: If you need me to provide you with any more screenshot or code please let me know.

Comment: Basically as a wrap up, as soon as I add: apply plugin: com.android.application or any other plugin, I get the error even when the rest is commented out, and I remove the plugin it works perfectly.

Comment: Normally you will put imports only inside the `build.gradle` of your main module (usually it is named "app").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. Inside `buildscript`, there should be only a single import. Like so:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        // do not add any more things here!
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.21.5'
        // do not add any more things here, either!
    }
}
```

If you want to import more libraries, add them inside your `dependencies` block.

So your updated `build.gradle` will look like:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
apply plugin: com.android.application

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        // maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:1.14.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    // replace following with your imports
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.5.0'

}

android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you had posted your gradle as code, I would have shown you exactly how your gradle file would look like.

Comment: I added it as a code, and as shown, even when everything is commented out and apply plugin: com.android.application is there, it will show the error, when I comment out //apply plugin: com.android.application it works perfectly. Thank you for trying to help me

Comment: Though thank you for the tip, in fact I didn't write it as such, it was like this in default when I first moved from eclipse to Android Studio, but I would change it if it can fix the issue

Comment: @coder I updated my answer with the fixed gradle file. Try it.

Comment: Maybe I should have noted earlier, that I have 2 build.gradle, the first next to it I have(Project: project name) and the second (Module: app) in general all the libraries imported are in the second, but the problem is in the first. Again both were created by Android Studio When moved the project from eclipse.

Comment: I have just added the second build.gradle which is not causing any problem, just so you may check it to have an idea. And truly thank you for your efforts.

Comment: @coder well it should work fine now. See the updated answer :)

Comment: Thank you for your help, It seems I was putting the dependencies in the wrong build.gradle.